# Only allow internal links within scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of URLs I'd like to scrape - 3000 of them.

I would like to go three levels deep on each url, BUT I don't want to go to external urls - only links within the domains of my start list.

I understand if I wanted to do this with just a few urls I would simply populate the `allowed_domains` list.

However when you get to 3000 urls, the `allowed_domains` list is too big for Scrapy to handle (it turns it into a big RegEx as far as I can tell) so it breaks...

Any ideas?

Something in the 'rules' list would be good.
`rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = (<local_links_only??>)) ,callback = 'parse_item'),)`

Or something in the Offsite middleware - anyway to get hold of the referring link?

or batching the job up? get 50 urls at a time? are there any hooks to allow something like this - I can see `start_requests` - but no callback for something like `finish_requests` that I can use to fill up the `start_urls` list again?

Guy

Comment: You mean that these 3000 urls are from different websites? If so, i think you better have separate spider for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [DepthMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.depth.DepthMiddleware) to control depth of request.
2. Use [allow_domains](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) to avoid external urls.
3. Tweak [concurrent settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items) to gain better perfomance.